# Can someone explain me the logic behind this sample c# code? I am not getting the answer 10 for the years

Tags: c#

```
private void assign(int num)
{
   num = 10;
{

private void doSomething()
{
   num = 0;
   assign(num);
   MessageBox.Show(num.ToString());
}
```

I get the answer 0 and not 10. can someone explain how this happens? my objective is to modify the variable.

Comment: 2 options: pass your num as `ref`, or use a `return` value. Both are keywords, try msdn to see how they work

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref

Comment: @xanatos: indeed... it must be otherwise this wouldn't compile... although the misplaced `{` is also an indication that this is not the actual code.

Answer (score 2):

As from comments you have 2 options, ref and out

1)

```
private void assign(ref int num)
{
   num = 10;
}

private void doSomething()
{
   int num = 0;
   assign(ref num);
   MessageBox.Show(num.ToString());
}
```

2)

```
private int assign(out int num)
{
   num = 10;
}

private void doSomething()
{
   var num = 0;
   assign(out num);
   MessageBox.Show(num.ToString());
}
```

Normally this is done by returning the value:

```
private int assign(int input)
{
   //some complicated calculation on input.
   return 10;
}

private void doSomething()
{
   var num = 0;
   num = assign();
   MessageBox.Show(num.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Stefan...This worked. Actually I am returning a bool value depending on certain conditions in this method so I cannot return the integer value. Thanks for the help..